# Groovy Templates - Non Standard Parameters, with minus signs

Tags: templates, groovy, template-engine

I'm trying to render a map that has keys containing minus signs (e.g. `first-name`). Here is an exemplary template I'm trying to render:

```
String text = "Dear \"$first-name $lastname\",\nSo nice to meet you";
```

When I render it with Groovy template engine (can be either `SimpleTemplateEngine` or `MarkupTemplateEngine`) it complains and throws an exception. When I remove the '-' from the variable name, it works OK.

Is there anyway to escape these variables in the Groovy template text?

BTW - the reason I'm doing it this way is to render a JSON blob from a 3rd party API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is at least one way to do it. It doesn't work in your case for the same reasons you can't use `-` character in variable name. When you define an expression like:

```
${first-name}
```

Groovy sees it as:

```
${first.minus(name)}
```

and that is why it throws exception like:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: first for class: SimpleTemplateScript1
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: first for class: SimpleTemplateScript1
    at SimpleTemplateScript1.run(SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy:1)
```

You can keep keys like `first-name` in your bindings, but you would have to put them in a map, so you can access `first-name` value using `Map.get(key)` function. Consider following example:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
def bindings = [
        'first-name': 'Test',
        'lastname': 'qwe'
]

String text = 'Dear "${map["first-name"]} ${map["lastname"]}",\nSo nice to meet you'

println engine.createTemplate(text).make([map: bindings])
```

In this example I put bindings into a map with a key `map`. When I do so I can access my bindings as `map['first-name']` and `map['lastname']`. Running this example produces expected output:

```
Dear "Test qwe",
So nice to meet you
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is awesome! It works :)

One more follow-up question. I'm trying to get above done with the MarkupTemplateEngine, with external files, but doesn't seem to like it.

e.g.:

    title("Fitbit User Profile - ${map[user].fullName}")